# OrientDB: Create Index using Java

Tags: java, database, exception, indexing, orientdb

I have problems indexing table/collection using jcouchdb. Actually it looks very simple but After some researches i dont know where the problem is or maybe i just blind. I followed the official test class:

https://code.google.com/p/orient/source/browse/trunk/tests/src/test/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/test/database/auto/ClassIndexTest.java

Take a look on the follwing code:

```
public class TestIndex {
    public static final String dbname = "indextest";
    public static final String colname = "object";
    public static final String indexAttribute = "ATTR1";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx ("local:/tmp/databases/" + dbname).create();
        ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx ("local:/tmp/databases/orienttestdb");
        db.open("admin", "admin");

        try {
            if(db.getMetadata().getSchema().existsClass(colname))
                db.getMetadata().getSchema().dropClass(colname);
            OClass object = db.getMetadata().getSchema().getOrCreateClass((colname));
            object.createProperty(indexAttribute, OType.INTEGER);
            object.createIndex(colname, OClass.INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE, indexAttribute);
            db.getMetadata().getSchema().save();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I always get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexFactory: Provider com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.hashindex.local.OHashIndexFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNIQUE_HASH
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexes.getFactories(OIndexes.java:76)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexes.getAllFactories(OIndexes.java:87)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexes.createIndex(OIndexes.java:117)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerShared.createIndex(OIndexManagerShared.java:76)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerProxy.createIndex(OIndexManagerProxy.java:68)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.createIndex(OClassImpl.java:1123)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.createIndex(OClassImpl.java:1085)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.createIndex(OClassImpl.java:1081)
```

Does anybody know the solution for this. I also tryied closing and opening db, save schema before and using different indextypes but without any positive results.

Second Question: Is it necessary to define schema to index columns/attributes in the collection or is there another way?

Comment: Of cource i'm using not jcouchdb as java api but the official orientdb java api.

Comment: Try: to add your vertexType + a dot, before the name of the index object.createIndex("V".colname, OClass.INDEX_TYPE.NOTUNIQUE, indexAttribute). I expect the name already exists, so you need a new name instead of colname.